# Submit button is not working. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The submit button is working when the function is defined on the same page. But it's not working when the action of the submit button is defined in separate JS file.

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="sjfb">
        <div id="form-fields">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
             {
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.controls);
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.formEditor);
             }
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit">Save Form</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
// in separate .js File)
$("#sjfb submit").click(function () {
  alert('Submit button is working');
}
```

I even tried the following methods:

```
 1. document.getElementID('submit').onClick(function(){*some code*}
 2. Giving a name to the function and calling it in onClick()
 3. $(#sjfb #submit).click(function(){...})
 4.$(#sjfb .submit).click(function(){...})
```

still not working. I can't find what is wrong with this.

Comment: Have you put your jQuery code in a document.ready event handler? Also note that the syntax should be `onclick = function()...` in your alternative attempt, although `addEventListener()` would be better again.

Comment: How do you include the script when it's in a different file?  (Yes, a script tag, but where in the page)?

Comment: I'm adding my JS file in 'section script' in my cshtml file @Archer

Comment: I've added all the functions in $(document).ready(function(){..}); including $("#sjfb submit").click(function () { alert('Submit button is working'); }); @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `$("#sjfb submit")` will not find the submit button.  Change it to `$("#submit")`

Comment: yes @archer I replaced with $("#sjfb #submit") and $("#sjfb .submit") still not working. Dont know what went wrong.

Comment: If those selectors don't work then they're being called before the element exists.  The included script must either be inside a document ready handler (as you've been told a tonne of times), or the script tag must be in the page *after* the form (preferably the very last thing before the closing body tag).  If neither of those things work then we do not have the information needed to solve the problem as it lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the dot on submit class event handler.

```
 $("#sjfb submit")
```

You should have:

```
$("#sjfb .submit")
```

Comment: or `$("#sjfb #submit")` 

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this snippet

```
$("#sjfb submit").click(function () {
  alert('Submit button is working');
}
```

Just to make it clear you should change it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sjfb .submit").click(function () {
    alert('Submit button is working');
    });
});
```

Or as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sjfb #submit").click(function () {
    alert('Submit button is working');
    });
});
```

since you've given class and id both as "submit" to your submit button. So you should add that to your js also.

Your entire code as tested on w3 is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sjfb .submit").click(function () {
    alert('Submit button is working');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <div id="sjfb">
        <div id="form-fields">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
             {
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.controls);
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.formEditor);
             }
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit">Save Form</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've given this before like you suggested it worked. but I want it to work even if I define the function in a separate js.

Comment: @Iswarya yes it will work that way also. include the js file just before the </body> tag of your html code within <script></script> tag. But since we are writing document.ready function so the location of <script> doesn't matter. Do it as follows **`<script src="demo_script_src.js"></script>`** where **demo_script_src** is the name of the js file. Also if your js file is not in the same location where you have the html file then give the full location in src as src="c:/newfolder/myjs.js"

Comment: @Iswarya Did you follow exactly what I mentioned in my previous comment?
If it doesn't work then share the locations of the html file and js file. also the content of the js and html file.

Answer (score 0):

if you load your javascript file before le dom content is loaded, then it can't bind the event on the button. try loading le js file a the end of the document, or you can add the event when the event $(window).on('load', fn) is fired

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        alert('Submit button is working');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with finding the element inside the `div`

```
$("#sjfb").find('button[type="submit"]').click(function (e){
    console.log(this);
});
```

This code will find the button inside the `id="sjfb"` `div` and will call
the `click` function.